# I am using captureStream with a frame rate of 0 to capture frames from a webgl canvas. How to trick requestFrame into thinking the canvas has changed?

Tags: html5-canvas, capturestream, requestframe

My understanding is requestFrame will not add frames to the stream unless it believes the canvas has changed. I want to have some periods in my video where the same frame appears multiple times in a row. How can I trick requestFrame into believing the canvas has changed?

Comment: Maybe the best would be to use a 2D context as a mirror and capture the stream from its canvas, from there you could easily draw a transparent pixel and that'd do the trick. For webGL I guess you'd have to at least preserve the drawing buffer, then I'm not sure how trivial that would be to draw again (or over) the existing content.